# Java Spring controller able to manage multiple POST queries at the same time and process according to the correct database state

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, multithreading

My example is very simple.
I created an endpoint to get JSON data from my interface (or client, or whatever). For this example, I will receive a Car json containing some colors. If it is a known color we have to use this one, otherwise the new color must be created.
Here can be a POST endpoint controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "application/json" })
    public Car digest(@RequestBody CarFormat body){
        return CarsService.digest(body.document, body.car);
    }
```

In the CarsService digest method, I have to verify each attribute and create the color if it is a not already existing one in the database.

```
    private Car findColorOrCreate(CarFormat car) {
        String colorReference = car.color.value;
        Assert.notNull(colorReference, String.format("Color reference not found from: %s.", car));
        if (colorService.existsByReference(colorReference)) return colorService.findByReference(colorReference);
        return colorService.create(extractColor(car, colorReference));
    }
```

As we can see, the service code is simple, it checks if the color already exist:

- if yes, it returns the color (returned by findByReference in colorService)
- else, it creates the new color based on an extractColor method)

However, I created a unit test (integration) to verify the behavior in case of two queries sent very near in the time:

```
 @Test
    public void should_createOneColorRecord_whenSimultaneousCalls_Endpoint() throws InterruptedException {
        String sameColorReference = "red";
        String json1 = "...car_id: 1, color:"+sameColorReference+"...";
        String json1 = "...car_id: 2, color:"+sameColorReference+"...";
        String json1 = "...car_id: 3, color:"+sameColorReference+"...";

        String mimeType = "application/json";

        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(3);

        executeAsyncRequest("/api/", mimeType, json1, latch);
        executeAsyncRequest("/api/", mimeType, json2, latch);
        executeAsyncRequest("/api/", mimeType, json3, latch);

        latch.await();

        assertThat(entityManager.createQuery("SELECT count(c) FROM Color c WHERE c.reference like '"+sameColorReference+"'").getSingleResult(), equalTo(Long.valueOf(1)));
    }
```

(Of course in my example, the reference is the color name and the new color doest not exist already, there is no color at all in the database in fact)

And here is the code of executeAsyncRequest, where I call the endpoint with each param, but using a different Thread - to simulate the real behavior:

```
    private void executeAsyncRequest(String endpoint, String mimeType, String json, CountDownLatch latch) {
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder builder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(endpoint)
                .contentType(mimeType)
                .content(json);

        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                this.mockMvc.perform(builder)
                        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                        .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
                latch.countDown();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

And, finally, when I run this test, the expected result must be 1 Color created, but 3 colors are created.
I tried to add Transactional, also @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW), on the controller, on the service, and the interface...
but nothing is working.

Can someone help me with this problem?
Many many thanks in advance

Comment: if there is only ever a single instance of the app, the simplest solution would be to synchronize the code block that creates the new color, but within that synchronized code block check again if the color already exists (double check locking).  If there are multiple instances of the app, then some time type of shared external lock mechanism would need to be used.

Comment: Thank you @andrew, can you give me an example of this synchronize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow up from the comments - if there is only ever a single instance of the app, then a simple solution would be to use double lock checking.  For example:

```
class ColorService {
   private static final Object lock = new Object();

    public boolean existsByReference(ColorReference r) {
        return ...
    }

    public Car create(Color color) {
        // this code is synchronized across ColorService instances, and only a single Thread can access at a time
       synchronized(lock) { 

            // double lock check - other Thread waiting to also create the new color will return since the new color was already created in another thread
            if (existsByReference(color.getColorReference())) {
                return;
            }

            // safe to create the new color
            return ... // insert into DB
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Here was my mistake, the keyword synchronized must be just after the public and no inside the body ^^
Thank you

Comment: Just to note: single instance of the application does not necessarily imply there is a single instance of the service class. Locking on a static final variable would be more fool proof.

Comment: Updated based on @Gimby's comment.